# External SDD mounts as root

Tags: permissions, mount

I have an external SDD drive which I have encrypted with LUKS and formated with ext4 (Label ext225).
When I click mount and open, I get the password promt to decrypt the drive and it gets mounted under `/media/bruni/ext225`. However, it gets mounted as root. Is it possible to get kde to mount this drive as user bruni, each time it gets mounted?

I am on Kubuntu 21.04 with the kde/backports ppa enabled. The drive has no entry in /etc/fstab

Comment: Does changing the owner of `/media/bruni` (when it is unmounted) help?

Comment: @Ray No, /media/bruni/ext225 is still user root:root, even after umount and remount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even for removable drives, it is normal that a file system that supports linux permissions is mounted for `root`. Only file systems not supporting linux permissions will be mounted for the user connecting the drive.

You therefore need to set permissions, either on the mount point if you want to assign the entire drive to a single user, or on selected folders on the drive.

To change ownerschip of the entire drive by changing the ownership of the mount point, execute:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/bruni/ext225
```

`$USER` is a variable that automatically will be replaced by your login name. Substitute another login to grant ownership to a different user.

Mount points of removable drives are automatically created and removed when the drive is removed. The ownership and permissions, however, are remembered.

Comment: That last sentence, saved me a lot of trouble (even  though nautilus is not something you would find on KDE ;-))

Comment: All right, sorry, I overlooked that you are using Kubuntu. I guess `dolphin` will also handle this `admin://` URI? I will adapt the answer. I just want to avoid that people start up their entire file manager as root using `sudo`.

Comment: No, problem. I just was being a smarta... You can revert to the nautilus answer. i used the command line anyway.  Btw dolphin does not seem to recognize the admin URI (I get `Unable to create io-slave. klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'admin'.` I did not know that the permissions of these mountpoints get remembered.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Then  I'd better remove this? This is a drawback of these different graphical environments: it all works differently.

Comment: yes, I would remove the reference to dolphin. And yes, this is the reason why i prefer the terminal for setting things up and the GUI when using.

Comment: This was exacly what I needed for Pop OS. Thanks